# handling errors within dispatch queue on the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I've the following code, trying to wrap my head around on how can I implement GCD (I'm new) with the following background call.

Not only I have to call the findAll on the background thread but I've to populate tableview as well (delegate calls `UITableViewDataSource` implemented which are expecting users to be populated), so there has to be delay in population of the table view.

Please do advise if there are better methods. Is `OperationQueue` the answer?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { // network call for data
        print("global")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // update UI
            print("main")
        }
    }
    
    do {
        users = try model?.findAll() // data for tableView
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Caught NSError: \(error.localizedDescription), \(error.domain), \(error.code)")
    }
}

func fault(_ error: NSError) {
     print("Caught NSError: \(error.localizedDescription), \(error.domain), \(error.code)")

}
```

---

table view context

```
extension UserViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    // number of rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        users?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    // cell contents
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = users?[indexPath.row].givenName
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

findAll

```
func findAll() throws -> [User]? {
    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM user"
    
    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw NSError(domain: String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)), code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }
    
    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }
    
    var users: [User] = []
    while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
        first: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)), last: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3))))
    }
    return users
}
```

Comment: What is `findAll` doing? Asynchronous network request or some slow synchronous task?

Comment: its not necessary, it can an IO (network/db) call, its send data back, the issue is how do you handle it on the front. added still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show some placeholder view in the table view when you are loading data. Once data is available remove the placeholder view and update the table view with data.

Comment: added the find All method

Comment: this is half answer, what about error handling? how do I trigger re-update of tableview?

Comment: If need to reload the whole table you can use reload data of table view (using notification or delegate). And for error handling, you can expose some method of placeholder view to update error in placeholder view.